# Transferring units from ALICE to BOB asking password

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I am trying to transfer some units from ALICE to BOB on local network but could not find password for ALICE or any of the pre configured accounts in documentation, also tried with empty password and getting the error as shown in the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkQsW.png)
I am using https://github.com/vue-polkadot/apps
kindly request you to help by providing the pair password for the pre configured accounts.

Comment: As this is a 3rd party app, they may not be monitoring this tag (as parity is) - The allice and bob accounts (if they are the same, using substrate-node-template I presume?) there is no password. The keys are here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/integrate/subkey#well-known-keys

If no answer here, you may want to log an issue with them https://github.com/vue-polkadot/apps/issues/new and cross reference/link here for visibility

Answer (score 1):

```sh
λ subkey inspect-key //Alice
Secret Key URI `//Alice` is account:
  Secret seed:      0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a
  Public key (hex): 0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Account ID:       0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  SS58 Address:     5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY

λ subkey inspect-key //Bob
Secret Key URI `//Bob` is account:
  Secret seed:      0x398f0c28f98885e046333d4a41c19cee4c37368a9832c6502f6cfd182e2aef89
  Public key (hex): 0x8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48
  Account ID:       0x8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48
  SS58 Address:     5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty
```

Here're the raw seed. Just import them and config the password yourself.